# backwards membership notation set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, math-history

This is more of a notational/historical question. I had a course last quarter where the professor would write things like $A \in x$ for $A$ a subset of some bigger space $X$ and $x$ an element of $X$. I thought that was a typo, but i've recently seen it again, on the 8th page (page 140) of this paper: http://individual.utoronto.ca/philipkremer/onlinepapers/DTL.pdf. I'm wondering if this is some old notation, and am curious about where it originated, if anywhere. Thanks to anyone who knows the answer to this.

Sincerely,

Vien

Comment: That is very strange notation to me. I'm interested to see the history behind this as well.

Comment: Thanks amWhy. I was completely unaware of the meaning of the symbol you mentioned as "such that." This looks slightly different though. It's not the epsilon that's backwards, it's its usage...

Comment: Oh, yes, you're correct about that...sorry!

Comment: Formulas are inside theories and in this case the author is using $A$ as a formula and $x$ is a theory. I am pretty sure $\in$ is being used in its typical fashion.

Comment: oh you're completely right Bageer. THanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Bageer remarks](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427964/backwards-membership-notation-set-theory#comment914995_427964):

> Formulas are inside theories and in this case the author is using $A$ as a formula and $x$ is a theory. I am pretty sure $\in$ is being used in its typical fashion.